# Close buttons- HTML Entity vs SVG

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout, responsive-design

When creating close buttons, usually for a card of some sort, I often find the need for some visual symbol resembling the cross/multiplication symbol we all associate with closing things.

In most cases, I find myself preferring to use the HTML entity.

```
&times;
```

But I've seen use of the "regular" x key on a traditional EN keyboard. As well as SVGs like those available at Feather and Hero Icons, so on.

What I would like to ask is whether there is a **recommended** option amongst these, and **why**? And if not, which option is most widely **supported** and/or most **performant**?

Thanks

Some background below, not necessary to read:

> The Entity felt the best bet for me, for a while. I was a fan of having to load or package one less asset into my app, however small, if I had the opportunity. 
>  This and, I'd assumed that what is the "x" key on my keyboard might mean different things and be different codes to different encoders across the wider world. 
>  &times(;) will only ever be &times(;). That's my hope anyways. 
>  That said, I've noticed some issues with what appears to be irremovable padding of that entity; whitespace above and below the character which grows rather large as the font size increases. As a result CSS cursor effects fire prematurely, at a point where the cursor is significantly (visibly) far from the symbol proper. 
>  That and the inability to adjust the equivalent of the 'stroke-width' property for that symbol have me wondering if these newfangled SVGs,  and all the unique features they bring, might be the best choice here regardless. `

Comment: a regular X or any other HTML entity size is depending directly to the font-size and its line-height. As such the size can't be set definetly. Espacially with user setting changing the default font-size the size might change unintended. SVG however is a scalable image which height and width can be set absolute and controlled easier through CSS. Also it allows for animations. However the SVG come in a slighly higher size. In 2022 the difference between 1 bit and 1kb should be ignorable.

Comment: Another thing to add is accessibility. WIth an SVG you can add an `alt`-attribute and label it there as close-button. That will allow screen readers to recognize its purpose and not only as "x". Last but not least, there are no compability issues. SVg is part of HTML and CSS. It is supported by every browser and e-mail client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience (as this seems like an opinionated topic), I don't think there is a recommended best practice. In the beginning, to achieve a working state, I would use a capital `X` since it's universally supported. Later on, the use of a SVG would be a good option primarily because SVGs are easily scaled for any device and are supported practically universally.